# How do I add a NAR dependency to a maven pom file?

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface, maven-nar-plugin

I'm trying to use JNI, and I'm using the maven-nar-plugin to package up the C++ code into a NAR. Now, I want to include this code in another Java project. How do I go about doing this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want to use the dependencies created by maven nar plugin.  From the [documentation](http://duns.github.com/maven-nar-plugin/index.html),

> Other maven projects may specify
>   dependencies on these nar files using
>   the standard maven dependency
>   declaration. Nar files get downloaded,
>   unpacked and installed in the local
>   maven repository, just like jar files
>   are (apart from the unpacking).

The [FAQ](http://duns.github.com/maven-nar-plugin/faq.html) has a section on how to load the native library from java code.

Hope these help.